# How to Use Summarise() to get the Average of Multiple Columns in Dataset

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to get the mean of multiple columns in this data set https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2019/2019-01-29/milk_products_facts.csv

What I am trying to achieve is getting the averages of all the milk products from the past 10 years (2008-2017.)
I so far have something like this.. but I am stuck.

```
milk_product_facts %>%
  group_by(year > 2008) %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), list(mean())))
```

If anyone can help me with this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mean()` will be not get the output as we are passing empty argument i.e

```
library(dplyr)
mean()
```

> Error in mean.default() : argument "x" is missing, with no default

We need either `mean` called without anonymous function call (or lambda)

```
milk_product_facts %>%
    filter(year > 2008) %>% 
    group_by(year) %>%
      summarise(across(everything(), mean))
```

Or use lambda function

```
milk_product_facts %>%
   filter(year > 2008) %>%
    group_by(year) %>%
      summarise(across(everything(), ~  mean(.))
```

Or if we are wrapping with `list`

```
milk_product_facts %>%
    filter(year > 2008) %>% 
    group_by(year) %>%
      summarise(across(everything(),  list(~ mean(.))))
```

Comment: thank you! is this getting the averages from the years 2008 all the way to 2017? I only see the rows when doing this but I would like to get the last ten years and put it into a line graph

Comment: @Marce do you need a group by 'year' or `filter`.  I was confused by your code

Comment: @Marce if you need the mean per year for each year after 2008, then do a `filter` before the group by 'year'.  Updated the post

Comment: my bad, yeah my code is wrong. I guess filter might be better to use. I want to filter the years from 2008-2017

Comment: I just saw the update, that worked perfectly! thank you so much :)

Comment: would it be possible now to create a `geom_line` graph with this information?

Comment: @Marce  After the output from above, you can do `%>% pivot_longer(cols = -year) %>% ggplot(aes(x = year, y = value)) + geom_line()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224171/discussion-between-marce-and-akrun).